# On IBM COS how to download file via browser using URL and proxy

Tags: ibm-cloud, object-storage

Need help on following use cases:

1. Need to download a file from IBM COS via browser using URL (any language python/GO )
2. Need to download a file from IBM COS via browser using URL via proxy server (any language python/GO)

Can someone please help me on this or share the sample code if have.

Comment: What research have you performed? Any results you can share? Anything not working from the available code samples? You didn't say whether the file is protected or if it is a sharable link.

Comment: What does it mean to download via the browser from a programming language?